# Matrix gradient and its directional derivative

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm struggling with finding directional derivatives of the gradient of a function of complex matrices.

As a first setup, consider a function $g:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$g(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{4}\big(\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-a\big)^2$$
where $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{A}^*\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $a\neq 0$.
Being a real-valued function, its derivative is the same w.r.t $\mathbf{x}$ or $\mathbf{x}^*$ from a Wirtinger calculus perspective. Therefore, its gradient $\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} g$ is
$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}g&=\big(\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-a\big)\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\\
\end{align}$$
and $\mathrm{D}\big(\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} g\big)[\mathbf{u}]$, the directional derivative of the gradient in direction $\mathbf{u}$ is given by (using Frechet derivatives):
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{D}\big(\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}g\big)[\mathbf{u}]&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}g(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{u})-\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}g(\mathbf{x})}{t}=\big(\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-a\big)\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}+\big(\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u}^*\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\big)\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\\
\end{align}$$

---

Now, consider the generalization of $g$ to complex matrices $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times p}$:
$$\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{X})&=\sum_{i=1}^pg(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{e}_i)=\frac{1}{4}\big\|\mathrm{diag}\left(\mathbf{X}^*\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}-a\mathbf{I}\right)\big\|^2=\frac{1}{4}\big\|\left(\mathbf{X}^*\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\right)\circ\mathbf{I}-a\mathbf{I}\big\|_F^2
\end{align}$$
When computing the gradient $\nabla_{\mathbf{X}} f$, I obtain
$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{\mathbf{X}}f&=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\big(\left(\mathbf{X}^*\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\right)\circ\mathbf{I}-a\mathbf{I}\big)\\
\end{align}$$
which seems to be correct as all my numerical tests are satisfactory. But, when computing the directional derivatives of the gradient using Frechet derivatives, I obtain
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{D}\big(\nabla_{\mathbf{X}}f\big)[\mathbf{U}]&=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\nabla_{\mathbf{X}}f(\mathbf{X}+t\mathbf{U})-\nabla_{\mathbf{X}}f(\mathbf{X})}{t}\\
&=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{U}\big(\left(\mathbf{X}^*\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\right)\circ\mathbf{I}-a\mathbf{I}\big)+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\big(\left(\mathbf{X}^*\mathbf{A}\mathbf{U}+\mathbf{U}^*\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}\right)\circ\mathbf{I}\big)\\
\end{align}$$
which fails my numerical tests. I also obtain the same result when considering the gradient and directional derivative in an element-to-element basis. Is there something that I'm missing, like the diagonal structure of the matrix $\mathbf{X}^*\mathbf{AX}$ with the Hadamard product in the chain rule? Haven't been able to obtain a formulation that passes my numerical evaluations. Thanks.

Comment: I see the typo, edited. The first setting is for vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and the generalization is for matrices $\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: Just as an addendum: I have confirmed by other means that my derivations are correct, both gradient and its directional derivative. The numerical issues came from the particular implementation of the library code I'm using. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the matrix $$A=A^H \quad\iff\quad A^T=A^C$$
where the superscripts $(T,H,C)$ denote
the transpose, hermitian, and complex conjugates, respectively.
Consider the following *real* scalar functions of the vector $y$
$$\eqalign{
\psi &= \frac{(Ay)^C:y -\alpha}{2} \\
d\psi &= \frac{(Ay)^C:dy+(Ay):dy^C}{2} \\
\\
\phi &= \psi^2 \\
d\phi &= 2\psi\,d\psi \\
  &= (\psi Ay)^C:dy + (\psi Ay):dy^C \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} &= (\psi Ay)^C
  \qquad({\rm gradient\,wrt\,}y) \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y^C} &= (\psi Ay) \\
}$$
Now substitute $\,Xe_k\to y\;$ (where $e_k$ denotes a standard basis vector) and define the component functions
$$\eqalign{
\psi_k &\doteq \psi(Xe_k),\qquad
\phi_k &\doteq \phi(Xe_k) \\
}$$
Finally, create your generalized function by summing over the components.
$$\eqalign{
\Phi &= \sum_k \phi_k \\
d\Phi &= \sum_k(\psi_kAXe_k)^C:dX\,e_k + (\psi_kAXe_k):dX^Ce_k \\
  &= \sum_k(AX)^C(\psi_ke_ke_k^T):dX + (AX)\,(\psi_ke_ke_k^T):dX^C \\
}$$
Define the *real* diagonal matrix $P = {\rm Diag}(\psi_k)$
to write this in a concise form.
$$\eqalign{
d\Phi &= (AXP)^C:dX + (AXP):dX^C \\
 &= 2\;{\cal Re}\Big((AXP)^C:dX\Big) \\
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial X} &= (AXP)^C
  \qquad({\rm gradient\,wrt\,}X) \\
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial X^C} &= (AXP) \\
}$$
Substitute $\,U\to dX\,$ then $\,d\Phi\,$ becomes
the *directional derivative.*

**NB:** In the above, a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(AB^T) = B:A$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only have one question: when you state $d\phi=2\varphi d\varphi=(\varphi Ay)^C:dy+(\varphi Ay):dy^C$, I don't see clearly why $\varphi$ moves inside the complex conjugate in the first term.

Comment: Since it's _real,_ it can be moved anywhere you want. I think it looks more symmetrical inside the parentheses.

Comment: I totally missed that. Thanks!

Comment: I just realized one thing. Your answer considers the directional derivative of the function $\Phi$, whereas I am looking for the directional derivative of these derivatives, $\zeta=d\Phi/dX$ and $\xi=d\Phi/dX^C$, which should be matrices. The good thing is that this further confirms that my gradient computation was correct :)